# How does pooling and resampling affect variance of sample mean?

Tags: time-series, variance, bootstrap, descriptive-statistics, resampling

Suppose I have $N$ independent random variables $X_n$. I draw a sample of predetermined size $K_n$ from each of them. Denote the average of each sample $\bar{\hat{X}}_n$, and the total number of observations $M = \sum_{n=1}^{N} K_n$.

Next, I use all the $M$ sample observations $\hat{X}_{n,k}$, with no regard as to which r.v. they came from, to construct the empirical distribution $\hat{F}$.

Next, I create $N$ new i.i.d. random variables $Y_n$ distributed as $\hat{F}$, and draw from the them i.i.d. samples of the same sizes $K_n$. Denote the average of each sample $\bar{\hat{Y}}_n$.

Let $T$ be some commonly used sample statistic that represents the dispersion; e.g., variance (or interquartile distance).

Finally, I compare $T_X = E[T(\bar{\hat{X}}_1, …, \bar{\hat{X}}_N)]$ and $T_Y = E[T(\bar{\hat{Y}}_1, …, \bar{\hat{Y}}_N)]$.

Under what (preferably intuitive) conditions would I find $T_X = T_Y$, $T_X > T_Y$, or $T_X < T_Y$?

Motivation:

I've seen bootstrap used in social sciences to analyze a large group of independent random variables. Specifically, the researcher would examine the variation in the sample statistics across these variables. If it seems that the variation is bigger than "expected", the researcher would draw some conclusions about the original r.v. But I could never figure out precisely what null hypothesis this approach tests, so I'm also unsure about what conclusions would be justified.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but as posed is quite broad. I think it will be asking quite a lot to obtain a concise answer which addresses your question as currently stated. Is there a particular form of the problem that is especially interesting to you? Also, are you assuming that the $\{X_n\}$ are *independent* random variables? That wasn't clear from your question. My suggestion: Reformulate the question to handle as concrete of an instance as possible. This will allow more concise answers and you should hopefully see how to go about generalizing from there. Cheers.

Comment: No, {$X_n$} are not necessarily i.i.d. (in fact, isn't $T_X$ = $T_Y$ if they were?).  I can see your point, but unfortunately, I am just trying to figure out the very general concept - so I can apply it in the future. Whoever answers this is welcome to narrow down to a reasonable case, but I'm really interested in as general an answer as possible..

Comment: Thanks, max. Note that I asked if the $\{X_n\}$ were independent *not* if they were iid. So, can you clarify this point? In any case, the answer to the question in your comment is, in general, "no, they are not equal". Cheers. :)

Comment: Ahh sorry! Yes they are independent! I updated the question.

Comment: Are 2 downvotes due to the fact that I cross-posted? I did read meta stackexchange on this topic, and it suggested it's ok if I link the questions and wait for a reasonable time before cross-posting. Given that the question was downvoted on the other forum too, I'll delete both of them. I just joined stats.stackexchange, and feel really unwelcome here.

Comment: I see only one downvote, max--maybe your comment got results :-)--but it's still unusual for any downvotes to appear without explanation.  Please don't take it badly.  FWIW, I agree with cardinal that it's potentially an interesting question, especially now that you have edited it to explain the otherwise abstract formulation.  (In the meantime, you may make headway by considering the cases where all $K_n=1$.)

Comment: Max, I've found both of your questions interesting and am hopeful you will get a positive answer. If I have some time, I may be able to put something together to get you started, but am stretched a bit thin at the moment. I would hope you would not feel unwelcome here. Cheers. :)

Comment: Thank you - if you think the question may be useful, I'll happily keep it on this forum, of course.

Comment: Yes, I think you should keep it on this forum. I've seen some questions go weeks without an answer and then all of a sudden get a really impressive response. There are two questions that I've been meaning to answer myself for a couple months now, but can't get the time to put together an answer that would do the question justice.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that each $X_n$ is distributed with mean $\mu_n$ and variance
$\sigma^2_n$, for $n=1,..., N$.

For each $n$, we draw a sample of size $K_n$, denoted by $\hat{X}_{n,k}$,
$k=1,...,K_n$.   Let $M=\sum_{n=1}^N K_n$.

Then, for each sample we obtain the mean
$$
\bar{\hat{X}}_{n} = \frac{1}{K_n} \sum_{k=1}^{K_n} \hat{X}_{n,k}.
$$

**Expected value and variance of each original mean**

The expected value and variance of each $\bar{\hat{X}}_{n}$ is straightforward.  We have
$$E[\bar{\hat{X}}_n] = \mu_n$$
and
$$\textrm{var}[\bar{\hat{X}}_n]= \frac{\sigma^2_n}{K_n}.$$

**Expected value and variance of each bootstrap mean**

Now consider the empirical distribution $\hat{F}$ obtained from the
combined sample of
$$\left\{\hat{X}_{1,1},...,\hat{X}_{1,K_1}, ... \hat{X}_{N,1},..., \hat{X}_{N,K_N}\right\}.$$
This is a mixture distribution.  A draw from a random variable $Y_n
\sim \hat{F}$ has expected value
$$\mu = E[Y_n] = \sum_{\nu=1}^N \frac{K_\nu}{M} \mu_\nu$$
and variance
$$
\textrm{var}[Y_n] = \sum_{\nu=1}^N \frac{K_\nu}{M}
\left(\left( \mu_\nu - \mu \right)^2 + \sigma_\nu^2 \right).
$$

Take a draw of size $K_n$ from $Y_n$.  Note that the distribution of
each $Y_n$ is the same.  Then, as before, the sample mean is
$$\bar{\hat{Y}}_n = \frac{1}{K_n} \sum_{k=1}^{K_n} \hat{Y}_{n,k}.$$

The expected value and variance of each $\bar{\hat{Y}}_n$ is
$$E[\bar{\hat{Y}}_n] = \mu$$
and
$$
\textrm{var}[\bar{\hat{Y}}_n] = \frac{1}{K_n}
\sum_{\nu=1}^N \frac{K_\nu}{M}
\left(\left( \mu_\nu - \mu \right)^2 + \sigma_\nu^2 \right).
$$

**Expected value and variance of the collection of original means**

Consider that a draw from our collection
$\left\{ \bar{\hat{X}}_1, ..., \bar{\hat{X}}_N \right\}$ is a draw
from a population with a mixture distribution with equal weights
$\frac1N$ and with expectation and variances for each component
already determined.  Therefore, the mean of this population is
given by
$$\bar\mu = \frac1N \sum_{n=1}^N \mu_n$$
and the variance of this population is given by
$$
\frac1N \sum_{n=1}^N \left(\left(\mu_n - \bar\mu \right)^2 +
  \frac{\sigma^2_n}{K_n}\right)=
\frac1N \sum_{n=1}^N \left(\mu_n - \bar\mu \right)^2  +
\frac1N \sum_{n=1}^N  \frac{\sigma^2_n}{K_n}.$$

**Expected value and variance of the collection of bootstrap means**

In a similar vein, we examine a draw from our collection
$\left\{ \bar{\hat{Y}}_1, ..., \bar{\hat{Y}}_N \right\}$.  Again, this
is a mixture distribution with equal weights $1/N$ and with expectation
and variances for each component already determined.  Therefore, the mean of
this population is
$$\frac1N \sum_{n=1}^N \mu = \frac1N \sum_{n=1}^N
 \sum_{\nu=1}^N \frac{K_\nu}{M} \mu_\nu = \sum_{\nu=1}^N
 \frac{K_\nu}{M} \mu_\nu.$$
Note that this is the same as each individual expectation, so that the
variance of this population is given by
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N \frac1N \frac{1}{K_n} \sum_{\nu=1}^N \frac{K_\nu}{M}
\left(\left( \mu_\nu - \mu \right)^2 + \sigma_\nu^2 \right),
$$
which can be rewritten as
$$
\frac1N  \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{K_n} \sum_{\nu=1}^N \frac{K_\nu}{M}
\left( \mu_\nu - \mu \right)^2 +
\frac1N  \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{K_n} \sum_{\nu=1}^N \frac{K_\nu}{M}
\sigma_\nu^2.
$$

Letting
$$\frac{1}{H(K_1, ..., K_N)} = \frac1N  \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{K_n},$$
we see that $H=H(K_1,..., K_N)$ is the reciprocal of the arithmetic mean of
the
reciprocals, so that $H$ is the harmonic mean of the $K_n$.  This allows
us to rewrite the variance as
$$
 \frac{1}{H} \sum_{\nu=1}^N \frac{K_\nu}{M}
\left( \mu_\nu - \mu \right)^2 +
 \frac{1}{H} \sum_{\nu=1}^N \frac{K_\nu}{M}
\sigma_\nu^2.
$$

**Consequences**

Since each $K_n \ge 1$, we have that $H \ge 1$, with equality only
when all the $K_n=1$.  Therefore, the reciprocal $1/H \le 1$ with
equality only when all the $K_n=1$.

Comparing the variance of the original sample means with the variance
of the bootstrap means, we see that they differ in two ways.  First,
the terms in the variance of the bootstrap means contain weights
proportional to the $K_n$ rather than equal weighting.  This includes
the centering value for the term involving the expectations. Second, the
terms in the variance of the bootstrap means are multiplied by the
reciprocal of the harmonic mean of the $K_n$.

Suppose the $K_n=K\ge1$, $n=1,..., N$.  That is, all the samples are
of the same size.  Then, $M=NK$, all the weights are equal to $1/N$, and the terms in
summation for the bootstrap means are the same as those from the
original samples.  If $K=1$, then the variance of the bootstrap means
is the same as the variance of the original sample means.  If
$K>1$, though, the variance of the bootstrap means is less than the
variance
of the original sample means due to the multiplier of the reciprocal
of the harmonic mean.

**Empirical check**

Assuming any of this is accurate, we can look at some specific examples.  Here is some code that should compute the given equations for the variance.

```
# Calculate the variance of the original means.

var.orig <- function(mu, s2, K) {

  N <- length(K)

  mu.bar <- mean(mu)

  v <- (1/N) * sum((mu - mu.bar)^2) + (1/N) * sum(s2/K)
  return(v)
}

# Calculate the variance of the bootstrap means.

var.boot <- function(mu, s2, K) {

  N <- length(K)
  M <- sum(K)

  mu.w <- sum( (K/M) * mu)

  v <- (1/N) * sum(1/K) * (
     sum( (K/M) * (mu - mu.w)^2 ) + sum( (K/M) * s2) )
  return(v)
}
```

Then, we can try some specific values.

```
# Set up some combinations.

Test <- data.frame(
    mu1 = c(0, 0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0),
    mu2 = c(1, 1, 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1),
    mu3 = c(2, 2, 2, 20,  2,  2,  2, 10,  1),
    si1 = c(1, 1, 5,  1,  1,  5, 10,  1,  3),
    si2 = c(1, 1, 5,  1,  1,  5,  1,  1,  1),
    si3 = c(1, 1, 5,  1,  1, 10,  1,  1, 20),
    K1  = c(1, 2, 2,  2, 90,  5, 20, 20, 10),
    K2  = c(1, 2, 2,  2,  1,  5,  2,  2,  5),
    K3  = c(1, 2, 2, 20, 20, 10,  2, 20, 30)
)

# Run through them.

for (i in 1:dim(Test)[1]) {

    mu <- c(Test$mu1[i], Test$mu2[i], Test$mu3[i])
        s2 <- c(Test$si1[i], Test$si2[i], Test$si3[i])
    K  <- c(Test$K1[i], Test$K2[i], Test$K3[i])

    Test$var.orig[i] <- var.orig(mu, s2, K)
        Test$var.boot[i] <- var.boot(mu, s2, K)
}
```

This yields the following results:

```
Test

#  mu1 mu2 mu3 si1 si2 si3 K1 K2 K3   var.orig   var.boot
#1   0   1   2   1   1   1  1  1  1  1.6666667  1.6666667
#2   0   1   2   1   1   1  2  2  2  1.1666667  0.8333333
#3   0   1   2   5   5   5  2  2  2  3.1666667  2.8333333
#4   0   1  20   1   1   1  2  2 20 85.0166667 18.8489583
#5   0   1   2   1   1   1 90  1 20  1.0203704  0.5635547
#6   0   1   2   5   5  10  5  5 10  1.6666667  1.3645833
#7   0   1   2  10   1   1 20  2  2  1.1666667  3.0989583
#8   0   1  10   1   1   1 20  2 20 20.4222222  5.1070295
#9   0   1   1   3   1  20 10  5 30  0.6111111  1.5871056
```

Empirically, picking larger samples from populations with higher variance tends to increase the bootstrap variance.